# Why signin window popup when I'm trying to get AccessToken using EWS delegate?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, access-token

I'm trying to read incoming mail. On authResult.AccessToken, Signin window is coming. why this is coming? If we are getting token to access mail(current user's mailbox). Then why signin is require?

```
var pcaOptions = new PublicClientApplicationOptions
 {
ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appId"],
TenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantId"]
};
var pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.CreateWithApplicationOptions(pcaOptions).Build();
var ewsScopes = new string[] {"https://outlook.office365.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All" };
// Make the interactive token request
var authResult = pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync().Result;
service = new ExchangeService();
service.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your using the AcquireTokenInteractive which will prompt the user for interactive authentication. What you can use is .WithPrompt https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-acquire-token-interactive?tabs=dotnet eg (You may also need to use WithLoginHint)

```
var authResult = pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(ewsScopes).WithPrompt(Prompt.NoPrompt)
```

.ExecuteAsync().Result;

This will only work if there is a cookie available

Authentication context is a bit more complex depending on where you are expecting it to come from and if you have any federation ? Usually you would use the token cache first https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-acquire-token-silently then catch the exception and try AcquireTokenInteractive if there is no current context. If you trying to use the currently logged on user credentials then you need to use the methods outlined in https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Integrated-Windows-Authentication-in-MSAL-2.x . You need to read the constraints though and it is not a one to one swap for UseDefaultCredentials